# Why are the ranges for my formatted text shifting in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring

My app includes a text formatting tool that offers buttons for things like bold, italic and color and shows the formatted text by generating an NSAttributedString and setting that to the attributedText property of a UITextView. After the user selects text and taps a button, I get the selectedRange property of the UITextView, then get the current attributedText property of the UITextView, add another attribute to the text based on the selected range, and then assign it back to the attributedText property of the UITextView again.

Starting with iOS 7, my text formatting started displaying at the wrong location in the text, usually shifted a couple characters forward. After some testing I noticed that this only happened after an empty line (e.g., a paragraph of text with two line breaks after it) and the formatting was offset by one character for each empty line proceeding it.

After more testing I found that when I set the attributedText property for the first time, any sequence of two line breaks is changed to a line break, then a "line separator" character (Unicode 8232) and then the second line break. The new characters are definitely added by the attributedText assignment, as I can see from outputting the integer value of each character immediately before and immediately after that action. However, the selectedRange property of the UITextView ignores the line separator characters, so any range that it returns is now incorrect.

I've already found a workaround, which I'll add as an answer in a moment. I'm mainly posting this in case anyone else is having problems with it. Also, I've reported this to Apple as bug 15349335.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this method to adjust ranges returned by the selectedRange property to account for these extra line separator characters:

```
- (NSRange)adjustRangeForEmptyLines:(NSRange)range inText:(NSAttributedString *)text byChars:(int)chars {
    int emptyLinesBeforeRange = 0;
    int emptyLinesWithinRange = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<(range.location + range.length); i++) {
        int thisCharacter = [text.string characterAtIndex:i];
        //NSLog(@"thisCharacter: %i", thisCharacter);
        if (thisCharacter == 8232) {
            if (i < range.location) {
                emptyLinesBeforeRange++;
            } else {
                emptyLinesWithinRange++;
            }
        }
    }
    //NSLog(@"found %i + %i empty lines", emptyLinesBeforeRange, emptyLinesWithinRange);
    range.location += (emptyLinesBeforeRange * chars);
    range.length += (emptyLinesWithinRange * chars);
    return range;
}
```

I can set the byChars argument to 1 or -1 depending on which way I want to adjust. This has been working for me for a few weeks now, but if anyone has an alternate solution, I'd be curious to see it.

Comment: FYI - `thisCharacter` should have a type of `unichar`, not `int`.